# Javascript, Ajax & JSON: weird "xml processing" error when parsing response

Tags: javascript, java, json, ajax

I make an ajax call with jquery `$.get()` which returns a json array and it works fine on some cases. On other cases however, in Firefox i get a weird error saying (translated from german):

> XML-processing error: syntax error

This is the structure of the json as shown in my servlet int the java console:

```
[{"key":"...","type":"...","content":"..."},
 {"key":"...","type":"...","content":"..."},
 ...]
```

And this is the structure when logged in ff console using `JSON.stringify()`:

```
[{\"key":\"...",\"type":\"...",\"content":\"..."},
     {\"key":\"...",\"type":\"...",\"content":\"..."},
     ...]
```

My request simply looks like this:

```
$.get(url, 
        {"operation": "search", "searchText": searchText, "types": types, "resultNumber": 99},
        function(data, status){
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    });
```

My java method for creating the JSON array:

```
private JSONArray parseJSON (ArrayList<ResultObject> aResultList) throws JSONException
    {
        JSONArray resultJSONArray = new JSONArray();

        for (ResultObject resultObject : aResultList)
        {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            HashMap<String,String> fields = resultObject.getFields();

            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : fields.entrySet())
            {
                jsonObject.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }
            resultJSONArray.put(jsonObject);
        }
        return resultJSONArray;
    }
```

Whats going on here? Where are all these backslashes in the returned json coming from?

Comment: can you post your `$.get()` request please.

Comment: Have you tried UTF-8 encoding on both your code page and the response source?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like that you'r response is not processed by jQuery as you expected.
try to add a

```
dataType:"json"
```

as option for you'r request, also take care that you'r server-side set's the right header on HTTP response (Content-Type: application/json)

because as I can see from you'r post, looks like that you pass a string to JSON.stringify

I hope that i help you, have a nice day

Comment: just had the same problem ... had to try the solution. "dataType" is not needed in the version of the pure enumeration.
Just add $.get a new parameter "json".
<pre> <code>
$.get(url, 
        {"operation": "search", "searchText": searchText, "types": types, "resultNumber": 99},
        function(data, status){
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    }, "json" 
);
 </code></pre>